# Laravel 10 Build - "EventEmitter" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external", imported by "node_modules/web3-utils/lib/esm/event_emitter.js"

Tags: vite, laravel-10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwb6i.png)

I'm unable to run the build for my Laravel 10 Application

I ran `npm run build` but rather than generating the build of the application, I only get an error stating that `"EventEmitter" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external", imported by "node_modules/web3-utils/lib/esm/event_emitter.js".`